# LESS is not working in Express Js

Tags: node.js, express, less

I'm trying to use less with express js

```
var app = express.createServer();
var pub = __dirname + '/styles';
app.configure(function(){
    app.set("view engine", "html");
    app.register(".html", require("jqtpl").express);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set("view options", { layout: true });

    app.use(express.compiler({ src:pub, enable: ['less'] }));
    app.use("/styles", express.static(pub));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

in layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.less" type="text/css" media="screen" title="main css" charset="utf-8">
    <head>
    <body>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        {{html body}}
    </body>
</html>
```

My style.less is

```
@color: #4D926F;
h1 {
    color:@color;
}
```

I can call http://localhost/styles/style.less but it is not render CSS.

Any miss in express configure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Set the `src` for `express.compiler` to your public root path, not /styles (same as `static`)
2. The compiled file will be at /styles/style.**css**

It's also good practice to have a `public` folder from where to serve static files. If you serve from root you're exposing your server source code.

```
var app    = express.createServer()
  , public = __dirname + "/public"

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', "html")
    app.register('.html', require('jqtpl').express)
    app.set('views', __dirname + "/views")
    app.set('view options', { layout: true })

    app.use(express.compiler({ src:public, enable: ['less'] }))
    app.use(express.static(public))
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }))
    app.use(express.bodyParser())
    app.use(app.router)
})
```

Comment: this answer is out of date. Express 3 no longer has 'compiler' method. Check this answer for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14368170/2031033

Answer (score 3):

less-middleware is a better alternative that works beautifully. A code like this should do the trick:

```
var pub_dir = __dirname + '/public';

app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: pub_dir }));
app.use(express.static(pub_dir));
```

Please note that when you author something.less you should actually link to something.css from your HTML or something.min.css if you want the file to also be minified. By default compilation/minification happens every time file changes, but you can configure the behavior. Please refer to less-middleware documentation for full list of options:
https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware

Answer (score -2):

I've published a [package on GitHub called node-kickstart-example](http://github.com/semu/node-kickstart-example) which uses a handy pre-configured express with enabled jade template rendering and less stylesheet processing. Use npm to install [kickstart](http://github.com/semu/node-kickstart), place your jade templates in `views/` and your less files in `assets/styles/` and your good to go…