# Node js express.compiler error

Tags: javascript, node.js, less, express

I am currently working on an express.js Webapp, Im working off the boilerplate app that comes with MS Webmatrix. I am able to run the app on my computer but when i push to nodejitsu or use another computer from which i got the app from git i get an error preventing server start.

```
app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] })
                ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
var app = connect();
utils.merge(app, proto);
app.request = { __proto__: req };
app.response = { __proto__: res };
app.init();
return app;
} has no method 'compiler'
at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hoopdog2\Desktop\afterthoughts_nodejs\serv
er.js:197:21)
at Function.app.configure (C:\Users\hoopdog2\Desktop\afterthoughts_nodejs\no
de_modules\express\lib\application.js:399:61)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hoopdog2\Desktop\afterthoughts_nodejs\server
.js:188:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

The dependencies that that app uses are

```
"node-uuid": ">= 1.3.3",
"everyauth": ">= 0.2.29",
"nconf": ">= 0.5.1",
"express": ">= 2.5.0",
"jade": ">= 0.18.0",
"less": ">= 1.1.5",
"socket.io": ">= 0.8.7",
"connect": ">=1.8.5",
"recaptcha": ">=1.1.0"
```

And i am using node version 0.8.7. Any suggestions to what might be causing this error is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is Express installed on the other computer that you are using? (Also, if you are deploying to nodejistu you might want to lock down the version number to = 2.5.0 rather than >= 2.5.0 since >= would pick up version 3.x which is significantly different from 2.x

Answer (score 2):

The `compiler` middleware for Express comes from the Connect framework and as of Jul 2011 Connect no longer includes `compiler`. So doing `express.compiler(...)` doesn't work anymore.

A LESS-specific middleware has been created and Express now uses that if you include it in your startup config. `express -c less` will add this line to the config:

```
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
```

If you have an older version of Express and Connect, you can add `less-middleware` to your `package.json` and add the line above to get it working.

It works pretty much the same as the original compiler, but includes some more bells and whistles.

[less-middleware project repository](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hector i resolved the issue. I had the wrong version of express installed and changing express to = 2.5.0 from >=2.5.0 and reinstalling dependencies has fixed the issue and i am now able to run the app. Thanks